# How to include ksshaskpass for git in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use ksshaskpass in combination with kwallet for my remote git credentials, in console everything works fine but visual studio code keeps asking me for username and password

I actually dont want to change to a credential helper.
I used ksshaskpass like:

git config --global core.askPass ksshaskpass

Answer (score 1):

For me, the fix was to set

```
"git.useIntegratedAskPass": false
```

in `settings.json`